# Can I use NOKIA \Here API's (REST) for getting GeoLocations(Lat\Long) giving Address Information as Input

Tags: geocoding, nokia, here-api

I am writing a Geocoder C# test Application . Can I use NOKIA \Here API's (REST) for getting GeoLocations(Lat\Long) giving Address Information as Input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokia did not offer a free RESTful Geocoding API to the general public at the until recently (see below):

Obviously such a service does exist as [here.com](http://here.com) uses it, and the various APIs such as the Maps API for JavaScript are able to process geocoding requests using a [**nokia.places.search.manager**](http://developer.here.net/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.search.manager.html), which in turn must be wrapping http calls to a RESTful geocoding service.

For Geocoding you have three options:

- You could use geocoding direct from the Maps API for Javascript - this is of course not RESTful

http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/places-search/search-by-address.html

- You could make an unstructured search by putting an address into
  the RESTful Places API. This a local search API and is not designed as a geocoder.

http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=37.7851%2C-122.4047&q=10+Downing+Street&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU&app_code=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&accept=application%2Fjson

- You could contact Nokia directly (see the link at the bottom of the
  [pricing plans page](http://developer.here.net/web/guest/plans)) and request a custom package including
  access to the "proper" geocoding service. This service would not be free,
  but would return proper geocoded results of a higher quality.

## Updated:

As of Sept 2013, use of the RESTful Geocoding API is now **available** to signed in customers - the documentation can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder)

Comment: Thanks Jason! I am trying out the Discover API . The only concern I have is ,It needs a Reference (Local) lat\long. So I might need to use some other geocoders to find the reference(Local) and then Use this API. So far its coming out good. Thanks for the reply. In case we need much better geocoder then we will contact Nokia.

Comment: There are several options when trying to create a hint location, either a) hard code a lat/long (useful if you are only interested in a certain area - you can get a country lat/long as follows: http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=0%2C0&q=India&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU&app_code=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&accept=application%2Fjson b) use the centre of a map  c) localise to a single city based on a free geocoder such as    http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html then drill down using the Places API.